# maximum (cap) value for CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

we're doing some crazy fun stuff with django-celery. A couple of our tasks take a while, and we'd like to let them do their thing. I tried setting CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT to a big value like 86400 (24 hours) and yet my tasks are still reporting TimeLimitExceeded at 5 minutes. I've read over the docs more times than I'd care to remember, but I cannot find anything referencing either a default value for CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT or a max value.

Two really valuable questions for us:

1. What is the maximum value for CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT? (right now it appears to be 5 minutes, or 300)
2. Why can't I set CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT to None? (yes, I'm pretty sure I understand the implications of potential zombie workers)

In settings.py

```
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 86400 #24 hours
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 86400
```

Comment: as a follow up, here's the worker log for a specific task:  
`[2012-03-26 18:32:00,025: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: asynch_periodic_update[e3a41c84-f070-4c68-a822-0a223efe1a42]  
[2012-03-26 18:37:00,403: ERROR/MainProcess] Task asynch_periodic_update[e3a41c84-f070-4c68-a822-0a223efe1a42] raised exception: TimeLimitExceeded()`

Comment: Turns out it was a false alarm. Our script to launch workers was being passed with a "time-limit" argument of 300 seconds (hence the five minutes).

Maybe my inability to find this overriding argument will help point someone else to a similar solution.

Comment: I'm in a similar issue. As far as I know, we're not passing a time-limit argument. I set CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT in settings to 86400 but I keep getting the TimeLimitExceed: 300s error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about default values... the defaults for `CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT` and `CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT` are both `None`.  These values are not documented, and a simple grep of the codebase won't help you out much either.  I logged all the values of the app's `.conf` to find out myself:

```
>>> import celery
>>> app = celery.Celery()
>>> app.conf
```